# Pandas concat creates an extra column and inserts the value in the wrong place

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a code in pytin which executes the following steps: takes first column, clean empty data, transposes data and passes it to the table. Code is below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
Name = pd.read_excel('Name.xlsm', sheet_name = 'Sheet1', header=None)
Table = Name
s_a = Table[0].dropna()
#drop unwanted column A and rename columns A to Z
Table = Table.drop([0], axis = 1)
# concat all parts together
Table = pd.concat([Table[0:8], pd.DataFrame(np.array([s_a.values])),Table.iloc[9:]]).reset_index(drop=True)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 3000)
Table
```

When executing the code I get the following output:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRW7s.png). I have highlighted the row which is appended to the table but it's not appended as I wanted.

I need that the first value of the appended row would be blaced to column 1, so it wouldn't create an extra column with empty spaced due to misplaced values

Raw data:

```
{0: {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: nan, 8: nan, 9: nan}, 1: {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: nan, 8: nan, 9: nan}, 2: {0: 'VO0001', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Jan'}, 3: {0: 'VO0001', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Feb'}, 4: {0: 'VO0001', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Mar'}, 5: {0: 'VO0001', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Apr'}, 6: {0: 'VO0001', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'May'}, 7: {0: 'VO0001', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Jun'}, 8: {0: 'VO0001', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Jul'}, 9: {0: 'VO0001', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Aug'}, 10: {0: 'VO0001', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Sep'}, 11: {0: 'VO0001', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Oct'}, 12: {0: 'VO0001', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Nov'}, 13: {0: 'VO0001', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Dec'}, 14: {0: 'VO0002', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Jan'}, 15: {0: 'VO0002', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Feb'}, 16: {0: 'VO0002', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Mar'}, 17: {0: 'VO0002', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Apr'}, 18: {0: 'VO0002', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'May'}, 19: {0: 'VO0002', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Jun'}, 20: {0: 'VO0002', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Jul'}, 21: {0: 'VO0002', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Aug'}, 22: {0: 'VO0002', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Sep'}, 23: {0: 'VO0002', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Oct'}, 24: {0: 'VO0002', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Nov'}, 25: {0: 'VO0002', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Dec'}, 26: {0: 'VO0003', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Jan'}, 27: {0: 'VO0003', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Feb'}, 28: {0: 'VO0003', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Mar'}, 29: {0: 'VO0003', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Apr'}, 30: {0: 'VO0003', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'May'}, 31: {0: 'VO0003', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Jun'}, 32: {0: 'VO0003', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Jul'}, 33: {0: 'VO0003', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Aug'}, 34: {0: 'VO0003', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Sep'}, 35: {0: 'VO0003', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Oct'}, 36: {0: 'VO0003', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Nov'}, 37: {0: 'VO0003', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Dec'}, 38: {0: 'FPL1001', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Jan'}, 39: {0: 'FPL1001', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Feb'}, 40: {0: 'FPL1001', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Mar'}, 41: {0: 'FPL1001', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Apr'}, 42: {0: 'FPL1001', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'May'}, 43: {0: 'FPL1001', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Jun'}, 44: {0: 'FPL1001', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Jul'}, 45: {0: 'FPL1001', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Aug'}, 46: {0: 'FPL1001', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Sep'}, 47: {0: 'FPL1001', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Oct'}, 48: {0: 'FPL1001', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Nov'}, 49: {0: 'FPL1001', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Dec'}, 50: {0: 'FPLH2999', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Jan'}, 51: {0: 'FPLH2999', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Feb'}, 52: {0: 'FPLH2999', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Mar'}, 53: {0: 'FPLH2999', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Apr'}, 54: {0: 'FPLH2999', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'May'}, 55: {0: 'FPLH2999', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Jun'}, 56: {0: 'FPLH2999', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Jul'}, 57: {0: 'FPLH2999', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Aug'}, 58: {0: 'FPLH2999', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Sep'}, 59: {0: 'FPLH2999', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Oct'}, 60: {0: 'FPLH2999', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Nov'}, 61: {0: 'FPLH2999', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Dec'}, 62: {0: 'FPLH3002', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Jan'}, 63: {0: 'FPLH3002', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Feb'}, 64: {0: 'FPLH3002', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Mar'}, 65: {0: 'FPLH3002', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Apr'}, 66: {0: 'FPLH3002', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'May'}, 67: {0: 'FPLH3002', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Jun'}, 68: {0: 'FPLH3002', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Jul'}, 69: {0: 'FPLH3002', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Aug'}, 70: {0: 'FPLH3002', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Sep'}, 71: {0: 'FPLH3002', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Oct'}, 72: {0: 'FPLH3002', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Nov'}, 73: {0: 'FPLH3002', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Dec'}, 74: {0: 'Total Supply cost', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Jan'}, 75: {0: 'Total Supply cost', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Feb'}, 76: {0: 'Total Supply cost', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Mar'}, 77: {0: 'Total Supply cost', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Apr'}, 78: {0: 'Total Supply cost', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'May'}, 79: {0: 'Total Supply cost', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Jun'}, 80: {0: 'Total Supply cost', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Jul'}, 81: {0: 'Total Supply cost', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Aug'}, 82: {0: 'Total Supply cost', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Sep'}, 83: {0: 'Total Supply cost', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Oct'}, 84: {0: 'Total Supply cost', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Nov'}, 85: {0: 'Total Supply cost', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Dec'}, 86: {0: 'FPL3002', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Jan'}, 87: {0: 'FPL3002', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Feb'}, 88: {0: 'FPL3002', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Mar'}, 89: {0: 'FPL3002', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Apr'}, 90: {0: 'FPL3002', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'May'}, 91: {0: 'FPL3002', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Jun'}, 92: {0: 'FPL3002', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Jul'}, 93: {0: 'FPL3002', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Aug'}, 94: {0: 'FPL3002', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Sep'}, 95: {0: 'FPL3002', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Oct'}, 96: {0: 'FPL3002', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Nov'}, 97: {0: 'FPL3002', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Dec'}, 98: {0: 'FPL3003', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Jan'}, 99: {0: 'FPL3003', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Feb'}, 100: {0: 'FPL3003', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Mar'}, 101: {0: 'FPL3003', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Apr'}, 102: {0: 'FPL3003', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'May'}, 103: {0: 'FPL3003', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Jun'}, 104: {0: 'FPL3003', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Jul'}, 105: {0: 'FPL3003', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Aug'}, 106: {0: 'FPL3003', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Sep'}, 107: {0: 'FPL3003', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Oct'}, 108: {0: 'FPL3003', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Nov'}, 109: {0: 'FPL3003', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Dec'}, 110: {0: 'FPL3004', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Jan'}, 111: {0: 'FPL3004', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Feb'}, 112: {0: 'FPL3004', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Mar'}, 113: {0: 'FPL3004', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Apr'}, 114: {0: 'FPL3004', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'May'}, 115: {0: 'FPL3004', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Jun'}, 116: {0: 'FPL3004', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Jul'}, 117: {0: 'FPL3004', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Aug'}, 118: {0: 'FPL3004', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Sep'}, 119: {0: 'FPL3004', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Oct'}, 120: {0: 'FPL3004', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Nov'}, 121: {0: 'FPL3004', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Dec'}, 122: {0: 'FPL3006', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Jan'}, 123: {0: 'FPL3006', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Feb'}, 124: {0: 'FPL3006', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Mar'}, 125: {0: 'FPL3006', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Apr'}, 126: {0: 'FPL3006', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'May'}, 127: {0: 'FPL3006', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Jun'}, 128: {0: 'FPL3006', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Jul'}, 129: {0: 'FPL3006', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Aug'}, 130: {0: 'FPL3006', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Sep'}, 131: {0: 'FPL3006', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Oct'}, 132: {0: 'FPL3006', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Nov'}, 133: {0: 'FPL3006', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Dec'}, 134: {0: 'FPL3007', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Jan'}, 135: {0: 'FPL3007', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Feb'}, 136: {0: 'FPL3007', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Mar'}, 137: {0: 'FPL3007', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Apr'}, 138: {0: 'FPL3007', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'May'}, 139: {0: 'FPL3007', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Jun'}, 140: {0: 'FPL3007', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Jul'}, 141: {0: 'FPL3007', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Aug'}, 142: {0: 'FPL3007', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Sep'}, 143: {0: 'FPL3007', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Oct'}, 144: {0: 'FPL3007', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Nov'}, 145: {0: 'FPL3007', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Dec'}, 146: {0: 'Product Cost', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Jan'}, 147: {0: 'Product Cost', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Feb'}, 148: {0: 'Product Cost', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Mar'}, 149: {0: 'Product Cost', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Apr'}, 150: {0: 'Product Cost', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'May'}, 151: {0: 'Product Cost', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Jun'}, 152: {0: 'Product Cost', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Jul'}, 153: {0: 'Product Cost', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Aug'}, 154: {0: 'Product Cost', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Sep'}, 155: {0: 'Product Cost', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Oct'}, 156: {0: 'Product Cost', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Nov'}, 157: {0: 'Product Cost', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Dec'}, 158: {0: 'FPL3019', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Jan'}, 159: {0: 'FPL3019', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Feb'}, 160: {0: 'FPL3019', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Mar'}, 161: {0: 'FPL3019', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Apr'}, 162: {0: 'FPL3019', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'May'}, 163: {0: 'FPL3019', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Jun'}, 164: {0: 'FPL3019', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Jul'}, 165: {0: 'FPL3019', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Aug'}, 166: {0: 'FPL3019', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Sep'}, 167: {0: 'FPL3019', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Oct'}, 168: {0: 'FPL3019', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Nov'}, 169: {0: 'FPL3019', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Dec'}, 170: {0: 'FPL3020', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Jan'}, 171: {0: 'FPL3020', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Feb'}, 172: {0: 'FPL3020', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Mar'}, 173: {0: 'FPL3020', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Apr'}, 174: {0: 'FPL3020', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'May'}, 175: {0: 'FPL3020', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Jun'}, 176: {0: 'FPL3020', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Jul'}, 177: {0: 'FPL3020', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Aug'}, 178: {0: 'FPL3020', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Sep'}, 179: {0: 'FPL3020', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Oct'}, 180: {0: 'FPL3020', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Nov'}, 181: {0: 'FPL3020', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Dec'}, 182: {0: 'FPLH3999', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Jan'}, 183: {0: 'FPLH3999', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Feb'}, 184: {0: 'FPLH3999', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Mar'}, 185: {0: 'FPLH3999', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Apr'}, 186: {0: 'FPLH3999', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'May'}, 187: {0: 'FPLH3999', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Jun'}, 188: {0: 'FPLH3999', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Jul'}, 189: {0: 'FPLH3999', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Aug'}, 190: {0: 'FPLH3999', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Sep'}, 191: {0: 'FPLH3999', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Oct'}, 192: {0: 'FPLH3999', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Nov'}, 193: {0: 'FPLH3999', 1: 'Total Value', 2: 'EUR', 3: 'CashUp', 4: 'MRF9', 5: '4667', 6: 'FY21', 7: 'Customer', 8: 'R001', 9: 'Dec'}}
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `print(Name.head(10).to_dict())` so we can see the raw data? Also include your expected output

Comment: I have added raw data

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Is it something like this you want to achieve? I provided some dummy data as the provided data only had `nan` in the `0` column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {0: [np.nan, 'a', 'b', 'c'],
     1: ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
     2: ['h', 'i', 'j', 'k'],
     3: ['l', 'm', 'n', 'o']}
)

#     0  1  2  3
#0  NaN  d  h  l
#1    a  e  i  m
#2    b  f  j  n
#3    c  g  k  o

col_0 = df.loc[df[0].notna(), 0]

#1    a
#2    b
#3    c

df = df.drop([0], axis=1)

#   1  2  3
#0  d  h  l
#1  e  i  m
#2  f  j  n
#3  g  k  o

# You have to keep the index of the original column, turn it to a DataFrame and then transpose it to align it to the correct columns
pd.concat([df[:3], col_0.to_frame().T, df[3:]], ignore_index=True)

#   1  2  3
#0  d  h  l
#1  e  i  m
#2  f  j  n
#3  a  b  c
#4  g  k  o
```

Comment: Yes, but I need to pass it to a specific row with index/number 8 and the data below should move down by 1 row

Comment: Edited and added slicing (my row is inserted on row 3 because of the form of the data).

Comment: Is it possible also to add specific column? it would, for example, add data to row 3 and 
 will start from column 2

Comment: In my answer the column alignment will depend on the index of the non `nan` data. For example, if the data in column 0 is on index (row) 1 it will go into column 1, if it is on row 2 into column 2 etc. From your comment it seems like this it not what you expect? Is your number of non `nan` in column 0 always equal to the number of columns - 1? In other words, will there be a exactly one value per column (skipping the dropped column 0)?